# Find explicit formulas for $d(n)$ and $\sigma(n)$ where $n = p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$

Tags: number-theory

[image]

This is what I came up with. Do you think this makes sense or does it need something else to help clarify something?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you assuming that both functions are multiplicative?

Comment: @ajotatxe Yes I would assume both are

Comment: Perhaps add the constraint $\sigma(1)=\tau(1)=d(1)=1$?

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebita-Dris Sorry, I am confused on why I should add the constraints? Can you please explain?

Comment: Because $\sigma$ and $d$/$\tau$ being multiplicative implies that $\sigma(1)=\tau(1)=d(1)=1$.

Comment: I am assuming, of course, that you know what it means for a function to be multiplicative, @mk2025?

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebita-Dris Ah yes, I forgot that part of the definition of multiplicative. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is essentially correct.

As you mentioned in the comments, you assume that the functions $\sigma$ and $d$/$\tau$ are multiplicative.

A necessary condition for a function $f$ (which is not identically zero) to be multiplicative is that $f(1)=1$.

> Proof: Let $f$ be multiplicative.  Then $f(x)=f(x\cdot{1})=f(x)f(1)$ (since $\gcd(x,1)=1$ for any $x$), which implies that $f(1)=1$ (since $f$ is not identically zero).